# Can I use TPM-based transparent storage encryption, and have a recovery key?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption

We have 100ish laptops that run Windows 10 Enterprise with full on Bitlocker encryption, but we want to go away from Windows.

I looked at multiple distros but none (and no open-source product) can propose a mechanism that does transparent encryption like Bitlocker, i.e. store decryption key on a TPM and provide recovery key.

We need full transparent encryption as we don't want to give the key to people that could lock us from the data on the drive, but still want a high level of security.

Is there something like that available in the wild?

Comment: Like this https://aboutcher.co.uk/2020/06/fedora-linux-luks-encryption-with-tpm-unlock/ https://blog.dowhile0.org/2017/10/18/automatic-luks-volumes-unlocking-using-a-tpm2-chip/ ?

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov, exactly what's needed

Comment: I've seen various articles regarding using a TMP with LUKS.  LUKS is setup such that there can be multiple (different) keys to unlock the drive.  This would let you embed a "skeleton key" in every drive as well as a key stored in the TPM.  Technically a skilled user may be able to extract the key from the TMP and use it to delete your skeliton key, however I suspect the exact same risk exists with Bitlocker.